# scarred me for Ramen (what does that mean?)

Tags: comprehension

Example ([YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upwqIDng_X8#t=20m20s)):

> Bird feces. Yeah. Nobody wants bird fices in their tomato bisque. Exactly. You're not leaving a used condom in my soup. All that aside. I'm sure that's happened. Not to me. If you've ever been to Tijuana, I'm sure, well, anyway. Well, I'll get a lawsuit out of it. Not if I'm in Tijuana, but if I'm in the States, I'm sure, if I get a condom in my food, I would be able to seek out some type of... I've had a band-aid. I don't go to that Ramen place anymore. Really? Wow, that's harsh. I'm actually, **scarred me for Ramen** and I'm just not interested, but, anyway...

I don't understand what the guy is trying to say. Especially, I don't understand his grammar.

Comment: The grammar is a disaster because it's a transcript of spoken English among at least two native speakers who are constantly speaking over one another.  If you break it into a dialogue with separate speaking roles, it makes a bit more sense, but most of the sentences are unfinished and/or leave significant amounts of information unspoken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When someone states that a specific item or event has "scarred them" for that item or event they are saying that they have been [psychologically traumatized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_trauma) by the item/event. Generally, this is stated alongside or as a supporting argument for an aversion to the said item/event.

This example states that they found something horrible in the dish that they were eating and, as the event traumatized them sufficiently, they no longer eat that dish to avoid any association with the traumatizing event.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't watched the video, but grammatically, that sentence starts one way, then changes structure. It is technically (very) incorrect, but this happens all the time in casual spoken English.

The introduction is abandoned, but the sentence doesn't start over. If both parts were complete, they might be something like this:

I'm actually...[mentally] scarred by the experience I had at the ramen restaurant [in which I found a band-aid in my food].

[The experience of finding a band-aid in my ramen noodles] scarred me. As a result of the experience, I am no longer interested in eating ramen noodles.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the speaker meant that going to "***that Ramen place***" caused him a mental injury that eventually healed but left a memento, a scar, which reminds him about the experience he had there.  Not a literal scar, of course.

By the way, "***Ramen***" is the name of a quick-cooking snack products, often noodles.  When speaking of "***that Ramen place***", they likely don't mean a restaurant with that name but some place that serves noodles (soup or other dishes).